# Two .RUN() functions from main function in Golang

Tags: go

A Go newbie so please forgive if the answer to my question is really simple but I have spent nearly four hours trying to make [Facktory Go Worker](https://github.com/contribsys/faktory_worker_go) up and running with API being written with Gin Framework. Here is how my main function looks like:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {

        go func() {
             for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                produce() // Function to push jobs to Faktory
              }
        }()
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })

    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080

    mgr := worker.NewManager()

    mgr.Register("SomeJob", someFunc)


    // use up to N goroutines to execute jobs
    mgr.Concurrency = 20

    // pull jobs from these queues, in this order of precedence
    mgr.Queues = []string{"critical", "default", "bulk"}

    // Start processing jobs, this method does not return
    mgr.Run()

}
```

Out of  `mgr.Run()` and `r.Run()` whichever is called first ends up blocking the other one so if `mgr.Run()` is placed before `r.Run()` the jobs are pulled from faktory server and executed but the server does not boot and it is the other way around if `r.Run()` is called before `mgr.Run()`. Any help in solving this or pointing me to the direction to sort this out myself will be highly appreciated.

The faktory server is running in a docker container using this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/contribsys/faktory/) but the jobs are pushed to faktory server so I do not think there are any configuration issues here.

Comment: Since both calls are blocking you need to execute the first one, whichever you want that to be, in a separate goroutine. The second one should be executed normally so that it blocks main from exsiting.

Comment: ...here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/eeUNkqxJ5fU

Comment: `go r.Run()` will do the job

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks your solution works. Please post it as answer so I can mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both calls are blocking you need to execute the first one, whichever you want that to be, in a separate goroutine. The second one should be executed normally so that it blocks `main` from exiting.

```
func main() {
    // ...
    go r.Run()

    // ...
    mgr.Run()
}
```

or

```
func main() {
    // ...
    go mgr.Run()

    // ...
    r.Run()
}
```